# leap year calculate in javascript

Tags: javascript

hey guys i have made some code to calculate the leap year, and below is what i get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Leap Year</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

 function calYear (year) {
    var yr = document.getElementsByName("year");
        if(yr % 400 ==0 || (yr % 100 != 0 && yr % 4 == 0))
        {window.alert("This is not leap!");}
        else{window.alert("This is a leap!");}


}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="yearForm">
<label>
<input type="text" name="year" >
</label>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

The problem is when i tried to put a number in the alert didn't pop-up, anyone have any idea why that happened?

Comment: you aren't calling your `calYear` function from anywhere.

Comment: There's nothing here that calls your function. You need to add an `onchange` attribute to your input field.

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a collection, so you'll have to specify the index

Comment: `yr % 400` makes no sense.  `yr` is a collection of DOM nodes, not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you needed to call the function, so I added an onchange attribute.
Second, you need to get the actual value of the text input, so I added .value.
Also, I used an id instead of name.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Leap Year</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function calYear(year) {
                console.log('calYear');
                var yr = document.getElementById("year").value;
                if(yr % 400 === 0 || (yr % 100 !== 0 && yr % 4 === 0))
                {
                    window.alert("This is not leap!");
                }
                else {
                    window.alert("This is a leap!");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="yearForm">
            <input type="text" id="year" onchange="calYear()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there any way to do it beside onchange?

Comment: are there any other stuff you change? i change the mis you told me in my old one but is still not work, i use your code but works pretty well, i thouht i missed on e some hing....

Comment: I also changed == to === and != to !==

Comment: you could do onkeyup or onblur instead of onchange